# Getting first element of an IEnumerable item

Tags: c#, generics

I am returning an `IEnumerable<object[]>` element from a function that uses `yield return` in a loop.

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetData()
{
        ...

        connection.Open();

        using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
            object[] array = new object[dr.FieldCount];
                dr.GetValues(array);
            yield return array;
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
}
```

What's the best way to retrieve the first element without using a loop preferably?

```
var result = Adapter.GetData();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short:

```
enumerator=result.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
enumerator.Current;
```

This is what a foreach does in a loop to iterate through all the elements.

Proper way:

```
using (IEnumerator<object[]> enumerator = result.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (enumerator.MoveNext()) e = enumerator.Current;
```

}

With LINQ:

```
var e = result.First();
```

or

```
var e = result.FirstOrDefault(default);
```

Also:

```
var e = result.ElementAt(0);
```

Comment: This is nice, thanks. But it makes me hit another problem and that is I close the DB connection after `yield return`, so if I call the function twice, it raises an exception saying the previous connection wasn't close. How come this works fine with `foreach`? Should I dispose something somehow?

Comment: Can you say what you used for getting the first element?

Comment: Cool man, I fixed it by passing `CloseConnection` behavior to the `ExecuteReader` function. Everything's working great now. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @David Weng - why are calling the function twice? yield return, to put it crudely, is like a pause. Till all the elements are "yielded" your close connection is not done.

Comment: @David Wenig - why using(...)? I think, enumerator is not a IDisposable.

Answer (score 1):

If your .Net 3.5 or higher

```
Adapter.GetData().First()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `result.First()`?

Comment: @DavidWeng: wait, doesn't IEnumerable have a `First()` method? Or have I completely misunderstood your question (could be)?

Comment: Am I missing a reference?
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]>' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @DavidWeng have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
enumerator=result.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
enumerator.Current;
```

Comment: The highest voted response actually has the exact same answer. It's hard to miss.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable items) where T : class {
        var list = items.OfType<T>();
        if (list!= null) {
            return list.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```